# exc_bad_access when trying to make a button disappear for a certain amount of seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a problem with my app. I have a login screen, I move to the next view controller with a button, then I have 3 buttons. 2 are hidden, 1 is not. I want the one that is not(red circle) when clicked to run the void button changer. However in this void I made a random number for the `int` I created RandomNumberButton. I made a `if` statement:

> If randomnumberbutton is greater than 30 then `redcircle.hidden = YES;` and `Bluecircle.Hidden = NO;` and `yellowcircle.hidden = YES;`.

The problem is I want the button to be visible for a certain amount of seconds. So I put this into the void buttonchanger.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ButtonTime target:self selector:@selector(setButtonEnabled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

whenever I run this piece of code it gives me the error:

> Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2

ButtonTime is a random number that is either 1,3, or 4.0 seconds. setbuttonEnabled is basically a void saying `set bluecircle.hidden = YES;`

bottom line: I am having the bug `Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2` at the specific line:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ButtonTime target:self selector:@selector(setButtonEnabled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`
```

EDIT: I changed arc4random to arc4random_uniform but I am still getting the same error

.m File:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.m"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

int RandomNumber;
double ButtonTime;
int RandomNumberButton;
int score;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667){
                // iPhone retina-4.7 inch(iPhone 6)
            }
            else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
                // iPhone retina-4 inch(iPhone 5 or 5s)
            }
            else{
                // iPhone retina-3.5 inch(iPhone 4s)
            }
        }
        else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 3.0)
        {
            //if you want to detect the iPhone 6+ only
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736.0){
                //iPhone retina-5.5 inch screen(iPhone 6 plus)
            }
            //iPhone retina-5.5 inch screen(iPhone 6 plus)
        }
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
@implementation Game{
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    YellowCircle.hidden = YES;
    BlueCircle.hidden = YES;
    RedCircle.hidden = NO;
       score = 0;
}

-(void)ButtonGenerator{
    RandomNumber = arc4random() % 100;

    if (RandomNumber>50) {
        ButtonTime = 3.0;
    }

    if (RandomNumber<50) {
        ButtonTime = 1.0 ;
    }

    if (RandomNumber>10) {
        ButtonTime = 4.0 ;
    }
}

-(void)setButtonEnabled{
        BlueCircle.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)setYellowCircleEnabled{
    YellowCircle.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)ButtonChanger{
    RandomNumberButton = arc4random() % 100;

    if (RandomNumberButton>30) {
        BlueCircle.hidden = NO;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ButtonTime target:self selector:@selector(setButtonEnabled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        RedCircle.hidden = YES;
        YellowCircle.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (RandomNumberButton<30) {
        YellowCircle.hidden = NO;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ButtonTime target:self selector:@selector(setYellowCircleEnabled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        RedCircle.hidden = YES;
        BlueCircle.hidden = YES;
    }

    if (YellowCircle.hidden = YES, BlueCircle.hidden = YES, RedCircle.hidden = YES) {
        RandomNumber = 0;
        [self ButtonChanger];
    }
}

- (IBAction)RedCircleButton:(id)sender {
    RandomNumber = 0;
    [self ButtonChanger];

    score = score + 1;
}

- (IBAction)BlueCircleButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)YellowCircleButton:(id)sender {
}

@end
```

.h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface Game : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIButton *RedCircle;
    IBOutlet UIButton *BlueCircle;
    IBOutlet UIButton *YellowCircle;

}
- (IBAction)RedCircleButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)BlueCircleButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)YellowCircleButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: I believe arc4random() takes as a parameter, the max value to return.

Comment: FYI - it is standard practice to name variables and methods starting with a lowercase letter. Only classes should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @MikeAtNobel You are thinking of `arc4random_uniform()` (which the OP should be using).

Comment: I double checked, and yes, you are correct: `arc4random_uniform()`.

Comment: Please post the code where the buttons are defined. Probably your header file.

Comment: Thanks. Guessed that, but wanted to make sure. Think I have your answer - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code 2 = Infinite loop.

ButtonChanger is calling itself since the condition is always meet, thus creating an infinite numbers of timer till the system gives up.

You should really follow guidelines how to write clear readable code. Avoid declaring lowlevel properties outside of a class or scope. Also keep in mind that properties start lowercase and classes uppercase. An reference/pointer to an object is a property too.

This is partly your code how it could look.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *blueCircleButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *redCircleButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *yellowCircleButton;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.blueCircleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.blueCircleButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, 100, 100);
    self.blueCircleButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.redCircleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.redCircleButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 100);
    self.redCircleButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.redCircleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(redButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.yellowCircleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.yellowCircleButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 200, 100, 100);
    self.yellowCircleButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    for (UIView *view in @[self.blueCircleButton, self.redCircleButton, self.yellowCircleButton]) {
        [self.view addSubview:view];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.yellowCircleButton.hidden = YES;
    self.blueCircleButton.hidden = YES;
    self.redCircleButton.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)enableBlueCircle:(NSTimer*)timer {
    self.blueCircleButton.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)enableYellowCircle:(NSTimer*)timer {
    self.yellowCircleButton.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)buttonChanger{
    NSInteger randomNumberButton = arc4random() % 100;

    if (randomNumberButton>30) {
        self.blueCircleButton.hidden = NO;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[self generateButtonTime] target:self selector:@selector(enableBlueCircle:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        self.redCircleButton.hidden = YES;
        self.yellowCircleButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (randomNumberButton<30) {
        self.yellowCircleButton.hidden = NO;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[self generateButtonTime] target:self selector:@selector(enableYellowCircle:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        self.redCircleButton.hidden = YES;
        self.blueCircleButton.hidden = YES;
    }

//    if (self.yellowCircleButton.hidden = YES, self.blueCircleButton.hidden = YES, self.redCircleButton.hidden = YES) {
//        [self buttonChanger];
//    }
}

- (void)redButtonAction:(UIButton *)button {
    [self buttonChanger];
}

-(double)generateButtonTime {
    NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 100;
    double buttomTime = 0;
    if (randomNumber>50) {
        buttomTime = 3.0;
    }

    if (randomNumber<50) {
        buttomTime = 1.0 ;
    }

    if (randomNumber>10) {
        buttomTime = 4.0 ;
    }
    return buttomTime;
}

@end
```